# Why REST PUT returns HTTP/1.x 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: php, web-services, rest

I tried this REST WS http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/

When I select PUT verb and copy and paste in textbox

```
firstname=Jim
surname=Example
email=jim@example.org
company_uid=1
```

I do get this response error :

```
HTTP/1.x 405 Method Not Allowed
Date: Sun, 18 Aug 2013 16:50:06 GMT 
Via: 1.1 varnish 
Allow: GET, HEAD 
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) 
Age: 0 
Vary: Host, Accept-Encoding 
Content-Type: text/html 
Cache-Control: max-age=172800 
X-Varnish: 244445725 
Connection: keep-alive 
Content-Length: 0 
Expires: Tue, 20 Aug 2013 16:50:06 GMT
```

Why don't I get as expected

```
HTTP/1.x 201 Created
```

Comment: `Allow: GET, HEAD` can't you add other methods?

Comment: It's not my site, it's a tutorial someone made.

Comment: On which URI did you send a `PUT`? Was it on `/tutorial/user/4` as stated in the tutorial?

Comment: I tested the service myself. GET, PUT and DELETE works. POST doesn't seem to.

Answer (score 0):

`PUT` requires you to know the specific resource ID already - it is intended to REPLACE the content of the current record with the content of a new record (that you provide). If you are just creating a new record that has never existed before and you don't want to replace or overwrite anything else, you should use `POST`.

From the website linked:

> There are two ways to add a row to a table:
>
> Using a PUT method we can write a resource to a specific URL, but to
>   do this we must already know the primary key we want to insert it at
>   (since the primary key forms part of the URL). The PUT method should
>   be used to create or overwrite a known named resource.
>
> Using a POST method we can send a rows representation to a tables URL
>   and get it to append it to itself. The POST method should be used to
>   create a brand new resource as a sub-resource of a collection (and
>   when you want the server to make up the URL for you).